# Android EditText setError() from string

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-json

I know I have to be missing something.  I get a JSONObject back upon error.

```
{
   "data": {
      "status": "error",
      "error": {
          "email": ["Email already registered"]
      }
    }
}
```

the JSON Key error is named the same as the EditText.  I need to be able to

```
email.setError("Email already registered");
```

Class.forName()  wont work for it .... How do I do this in Android

The value is in a Iterator key = "email"

```
} else if (data.getString("status").equals("error")) {
    Log.d(Constants.LOG, "No Account Found Sending to Register!");   
    JSONObject errors = data.getJSONObject("error");
    for(Iterator<String> iter = errors.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
        String key = iter.next();
        Object value = errors.get(key);
        Log.d(Constants.LOG,value.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"",""));
                                ///Class<?> clasz = Class.forName(key);
     }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + data.getString("error"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: post your parsing and where you set it to textview/edittext

Comment: post your parsing logic

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: I am iterating the errors JSONObject to get the Field and the Error.  For the most part I validate on the App side except for the email which needs to be server side validated   See the code I just edited

Comment: Is your **data** an object class? Can you also include that, if possible?

Comment: what I understand is you have to set error to the field named `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible way is to use `switch` case for the field name if you have java 1.7 or above

```
for(Iterator<String> iter = errors.keys();iter.hasNext();) {
    String key = iter.next();
    Object value = errors.get(key);
    Log.d(Constants.LOG,value.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("\"",""));
    switch(key) {
        case "email":
                    email.setError(value.toString());
                    break;
        case "name":
                    name.setError(value.toString());
                    break;
    }
 }
```

**OR**

You can achieve same by using [`Java Reflection API`](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-reflection) if you don't want to use `switch` case.